# How to display only date in GridView when pulling data from a DB? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, date, gridview

I am pulling data from an access database to show in a GridView control on a ASP.NET project.  It works fine but I want to see if I can format the data that is being pulled.  Currently any currency is being truncated from xx.xx to just the dollar amounts.  Also the dates are displaying mm/dd/yyyy hh/mm/ss AM/PM

I tried editing the database itself to the right values (I set the currency field to "Currency" and the date field to "Short Date" but when I pull that date it still shows them not formatted.

**EDIT:** Sorry, had to take the code down

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question with some example code.

Comment: Please add markup for the gridview from the aspx page. Likely need to set the format string for the columns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in the grid view of yours add the property called `DataFormatString`

**DataFormatString examples:**

```
{0:dd MMMM yyyy}    -    gives 24 February 2006
{0:MMM dd}          -    gives Feb 24 (substitue MMM with MMMM for the full month name 
                         instead of abbreviation) 
{0:dd/MM/yy}        -    gives 24/02/06 
{0:dd/MM/yyyy}      -    gives 24/02/2006
```

**Sample Code**

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" 
                DataField="SampleDate" 
                DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"  >
```

## [MSDN BoundField.DataFormatString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! This works great but now I'm getting the formatted columns and next to them another set from the code generated columns that are unformatted.  Code I used: <asp:BoundField DataField="PayRate" 
 HeaderText="Rate"    SortExpression="PayRate" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />

Comment: Amarnath, I'm not getting any errors but duplicate columns such as: http://goo.gl/BVbprD

Comment: add autogeneratecolumns in the grid to false this property is to be added after the ID of the GridView

Comment: Use `DataFormatString="{0:d}"` to localize it for any culture.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the dataformatstring with how you want it to be populated.

As exemplified on the MSDN page:

Money:

```
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Price" DataField="Price"
                                     DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
```

With the {0:c}, placing a number after the c value (such as {0:c2}) will give you that many decimal places.

Date:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="MyDate" dataformatstring="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if you are using Template Field:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="last_modified_date">
    <ItemTemplate>                           
        <asp:Label ID="lblModyDate" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase" 
Text='<%# Bind("last_modified_date","{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:tt}") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvLEmployees" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                                <%# Eval("Name")  %>                             
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                             <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("JoinDate")).ToShortDateString() %>
OR
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("JoinDate")).ToString("d") %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>
        </Column>
        </Gridview>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Create a BoundField, set its properties including the property dataformatstring which you can use to set format of the field appear in the GridView, and add it to the GridView control.

here below some code

```
 public GridView Cr_GridView(string[] ColNames,string[] ColLable, string[] ColFormat)
        {
            GridView GV = new GridView();
            int x = ColNames.GetUpperBound(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                BoundField GvField = new BoundField();

                GvField.DataField = ColNames[i];
                GvField.HeaderText = ColLable[i];
                GvField.DataFormatString = ColFormat[i];// for example "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" for a date field

                GV.Columns.Add(GvField);
            }
            return GV;
        }
```